# Отправка формы без подтверждения

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форма с полями, action'ом, всё работает. Мне нужно сделать так, чтоб форма была без кнопки, и просто осуществлялся бы переход по адресу формы при потере фокуса, т.е. отправлялся бы POST-запрос. Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: Можете объяснить более подробно то что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

через js вы можете вручную сабмитить форму.

```
document.getElementById('YOUR_FORM_ID').submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("qwe").addEventListener("blur", function() {
  this.submit();
}, true);
```

```html
<form action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="POST" id="qwe">
  <input name="t" placeholder="Введите что-нибудь и снимите фокус">
</form>
```